# Is it possible to fetch only the message id via fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder method?

Tags: email, mailcore2

Any way to set the `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindUid` to fetch only the message `id` and `uid`?

Comment: Are you looking for the property `extraHeaders` of `MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation`?

Comment: I want to fetch only the message id and uid via MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation, I don't want to get the the full header.